# Bootstrap Lightbox no action

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox, bootstrap-lightbox

I have a simple snippet of the code here and can't get it to work. I included all assets including the lightbox css and js. Here is my code:

```
<a data-toggle="lightbox" data-target="#image" class="thumbnail">
   <img src="../app/uploads/test.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</a>

<div id="image" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class='lightbox-content'>
   <img src="../app/uploads/test.jpg">
   <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Caption here</p></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click the image, nothing happens but the url doesn't change like `someUrl` to `someUrl#image` so I think it reads the code but doesn't pop up the image. Am I missing something?

Comment: use `data-target` instead of `href`

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="lightbox" data-target="#image" class="thumbnail">

Comment: You need to make a jsfiddle or provide a link and which bootstrap lightbox are you using? There is more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with Boostrap `Modal`, Its pretty easy . Here is the small example I can show.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#HoastedModal" class="btn btn-info">Hoasted Modal</a>
<br>
    <br>
<p>This JSFiddle is part of a <a href="https://www.hoasted.com/bootstrap-3-modal-example-with-jsfiddle">Hoasted webhosting blogpost</a></p>

<div id="HoastedModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="modal-label">Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Content.</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!--modal-content-->
    </div> <!--modal-dialog-->
</div> <!--modal-->
```